# Given the Green function, can we construction the differential operator and boundary condition of it

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I learnt that Green function is the impulse response of a differential operator with certain boundary condition, can we ask the reverse question, namely given the Green function, can we construction the differential operator and boundary condition of it.